# client to scan the memory of the HDFS cluster and report the consumed space percentage

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hbase, hdfs

I am very new to Hadoop and got the requirement as

To write the client program that scans the memory of the HDFS Cluster and reports the consumed space available percentage.

Any help will be appreciated as i am very new to the Hadoop Stuffs.

Regards,
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hadoop dfsadmin -report` to get all stats regarding the cluster. The output would be something like this:

```
hadoop dfsadmin -report

Configured Capacity: 30224303030272 (27.49 TB)
Present Capacity: 28080468025269 (25.54 TB)
DFS Remaining: 11862609379328 (10.79 TB)
DFS Used: 16217858645941 (14.75 TB)
DFS Used%: 57.75%
Under replicated blocks: 47
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 63
Missing blocks: 47

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (9):

Name: 111.111.111.111:50010
Hostname: $hostname
Rack: /default
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 2240100818944 (2.04 TB)
DFS Used: 1258469347618 (1.14 TB)
Non DFS Used: 179970305758 (167.61 GB)
DFS Remaining: 801661165568 (746.61 GB)
DFS Used%: 56.18%
DFS Remaining%: 35.79%
Configured Cache Capacity: 4294967296 (4 GB)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 4294967296 (4 GB)
Cache Used%: 0.00%
Cache Remaining%: 100.00%
Last contact: Fri Dec 12 12:36:32 IST 2014
```

Comment: Yes, we can do this way.
But we don`t need to do this from the Unix Console.
I need to do with the JAVA Client Code.

Comment: I Figured one of the way like

Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://location");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

long capacity = fs.getStatus().getCapacity();
long used = fs.getStatus().getUsed();
long remaining = fs.getStatus().getRemaining();

This gives the whole cluster HDFS information.

But i m stuck that i want all the nodes information as well which are in the cluster.

Comment: How can we get these details on console through the JAVA Client code and not using hadoop dfsadmin -dfsreport  ??